# При переносе вопроса с основного сайта на Мету вешается непереведённая метка

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, метки, перенос-вопросов

Вопрос только что перенесён с основного сайта на Мету. Обратите внимание, что присвоена метка [discussion].

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1826/1

Здесь должна быть переведённая метка [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), но система создаёт вопрос в обход автозамены меток.

Comment: Все еще воспроизводится 25 января 2016.